# Is the word "I'm" pronounced like /əm/, instead of /aɪm/, when it is unstressed?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, ipa

Is the word "I'm" pronounced like /ʌm/ or /əm/, instead of /aɪm/, when it is unstressed?

Comment: In which accent?

Comment: This Brit will sometimes say /ʌm/, sometimes /aɪm/. But never /əm/.

Comment: I would use something between /ɐm/ and /ʌm/ if unstressed and /ɐɪm/ when stressed (Southern England).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it could be, in the U.S. at least, especially when talking quickly.  Example:

> She said we don't have to be there until 3:00, and anyway I'm not ready yet.

Comment: I would say it’s much more common to hear it reduced to [ɑm] or perhaps even [am] or [ɛm]. I don’t recall hearing it reduced all the way down to a schwa.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for the comment ^^. But what is the difference between [ɑm] and [am]?

Comment: @Edinburgh1 [a] is the sound in _hat_; [ɑ] is the sound in _father_.